# Python: Removing a last element from list of list?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, text

Given a List `A`. I want to remove the last element (`b,'zz')`of each list with list `A`.

```
A = [ [(a,'rr'),(c,'rr'),(d,'rr'),(b,'zz')],
      [(g,'rr'),(h,'rr'),(e,'rr'),(b,'zz')],
      [(c,'rr'),(r,'rr'),(s,'rr'),(b,'zz')] ]
```

What I tried.

```
for i in A:
    N = del i[-1]
```

But it is not working.

Comment: Just `del i[-1]` without assignment.

Comment: Please always include the full error message you get, *it is not working* is not a valid problem description. You get a *syntax error* exception in this case, because `del` is a statement and can't be used in an expression.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `list.pop()` method:

```
for i in A:
    i.pop()
```

Reference: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html

Answer (score 5):

You could simply *slice* up till the last item in a list comprehension:

```
A = [l[:-1] for l in A]
```

Comment: The problem with slicing and list comprehension is that it involves lists copying, which consumes time and space. This would be necessary only with a list of tuples instead of list of lists.

Comment: @AntoinePinsard Your points are valid. One could still save some space by assigning to the original list with `A[:]`. Thanks for noting.

Answer (score 2):

`del` is a statement and must be used accordingly. Most importantly, it cannot be used in an assignment.

Simply remove the assignment:

```
for i in A:
  del i[-1]
```